# Analytic Solution to Integral

Tags: integration, power-series, taylor-expansion, improper-integrals

Is there any analytic solution to the following integral?

$$-\frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\ln{(1+e^x)}\exp{\Big\{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}\Big\}dx$$

where $\mu\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\sigma\in\mathbb{R}^+$.

I've tried to exploit the Taylor series of the natural logarithm (using $\ln{(1+e^x)}$ from $0$ to $-\infty$ and $x+\ln{(1+e^{-x})}$ from $0$ to $\infty$) to get the following equivalent form:

$$\mu\Big\{-1+erf\Big(\frac{\mu}{\sigma\sqrt{2}}\Big)\Big\}-\frac{2\sigma}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{\mu^2}{2\sigma^2}}+\frac{2e^{-\frac{\mu^2}{2\sigma^2}}}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^l}{l!}n^l\big(2\sigma^2\big)^{\frac{l+1}{2}}\Gamma\Big(\frac{l+1}{2}\Big)\sum_{0\leq k\leq l,\text{ k ODD}}\binom{l}{k}\Big(\frac{\mu}{n\sigma^2}\Big)^k$$

where $\Gamma(\cdot)$ is the gamma function.

But I don't know how to proceed from that.

Comment: By "analytic solution", you mean calculating antiderivative, or just computing the value?

Comment: The Maclaurin series of $\ln(1+x)$ only has a radius of convergence of $1$, so you can only use this to compute the integral from $-\infty$ to $0$. This also explains why the original integral is finite while your sum is not. From 0 to infinity if you want to use Taylor methods again then you should be using $\ln(1+e^x)=x+\ln(1+e^{-x})$.

Comment: @Ian the question has been modified updating the second formula with the two Taylor expansions